# Color de fondo del botón

Tags: java, java-swing, macos

Estoy intentando cambiar el color de fondo del botón y no el de detrás. A mis compañeros del proyecto les funciona bien, **trabajan con Windows, yo con Mac**. No se si eso influye en algo para que no me funcione a mí.

Este es el código:

```
        JButton resp1 = new JButton("");
        resp1.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        resp1.setText(pregunta.getRespuesta_1());
        resp1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (contestado == false) {
                int boton = 1;

                if (boton == pregunta.getCorrecta()) {
                    acierto=true;
                    resp1.setBackground(Color.green);
                    resp1.setOpaque(true);
                    resp1.setBorder(null);
                } else {
                    resp1.setBackground(Color.red);
                    resp1.setOpaque(true);

                }
                contestado = true;
                button.setText("Continuar");
                button.setOpaque(true);
                button.setContentAreaFilled(true);
                button.setBorderPainted(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

El problema que no veo la forma de que conserve la forma del botón con el el fondo de diferente color, que en este caso es rojo o verde dependiendo de si se acierta o no.

Answer (score 1):

Para que no se pinte el borde usa:

```
setBorderPainted(false);
```

Setear el borde a null es una mala práctica.

Asegúrate de que el área se pinta y de que es opaco.

Además, estando en OSX, tienes que tener en cuenta que el 'Look and Feel' de tu Mac puede estar ignorando el color de fondo del boton, prueba con otro 'Look and Feel'. Esto debería funcionar:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Vers recuerda que la clase **WindowsClassicLookAndFeel** solo está disponible en Windows.

Comment: Según la documentación de Oracle el **WindowsClassicLookAndFeel no está ligado al OS**.   
[The GTK+, Motif, and Windows L&Fs are provided by Sun and shipped with the Java SDK and JRE, although they are not part of the Java API.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available)

Comment: Compila la linea que pusiste en el mensaje y ejecutala en **Mac o Linux**, entonces verás la realidad.